# Copying values and formulas from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a template spreadsheet and multiple copies of it. I need to be able to update the template spreadsheet's sheets (be it values or formulas) and quickly reflect theses changes across all the spreadsheet copies.

The obstables are:

1. The [copy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) method does not work in this case because it only works *within the same spreadsheet*;
2. Copying an entire sheet also does not work because it breaks the charts (adding a new sheet, removing old one, renaming new sheet);

I tried to use [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [getFormulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas()) and then use the following code to have one complement the other:

```
var combined = []
for (cell in templateValues) {
  var row = [];
  if (templateValues[cell] == '') {
    row.push(templateFormulas[cell])
  } else {
    row.push(templateValues[cell])
  }
  combined.push(row);
}
Logger.log(combined)
```

and then using

```
var targetRange = targetSheets[sheet].getRange(1, 1, combined.length, combined[0].length);
targetRange.setValues(combined);
```

to paste the values. That did not work (values weren't pasted in the right place nor were formulas).

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Including some sample spreadsheets for clarity.

[Source Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kUaSYKk4kQEDP9tcnkurHeBeMDBA94LkBRoeNSpETEc/edit?usp=sharing) and [Target Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y-GvWa5gO6jd4IFGECnVIvuaIkd6jXJP41J8YPVwQpk/edit?usp=sharing).

Again, the point is that I can copy everything in the "SameSheet" sheet of the Source Spreadsheet to the "SameSheet" sheet of the Target Spreadsheet (in the actual use case it is a Drive folder with multiple target spreadsheets).

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet for thinking of the solution? And can you show us the input and output you want? I think that they will help users think of it.

Comment: Added 2 sample spreadsheets, let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your response. As you know, "copyTo(destination)" can be used for the same spreadsheet. There is a workaround using this. The flow is as follows. 1. Copy the source sheet (template sheet) of Source spreadsheet to the target spreadsheet. 2. Copy the data range of the copied sheet to the target sheet using "copyTo(destination)". 3. Delete the copied sheet (template sheet). By this flow, the sheet ID of the target sheet is not changed and can copy all values, formulas and format. How about this flow? If you need, I can propose the sample script.

Comment: That makes sense and will work I guess (haven't tried it). I was seeing if there was a simpler way of doing this but I guess I'll have to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. If you have any questions, feel free to tell me.